# Increase DIV height after replacing its HTML using AJAX

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div element with a certain id, and I make an AJAX call to get some data and replace the HTML of that div element with the new data.

However, the trouble is that, the height of my container does not increase even after the addition of the new HTML element within that DIV. How can I get the height to increase.

Thanks.

Comment: And you dont define the height in your CSS or something else? My guess its a CSS error. Could you paste some code? :)

Comment: Do you have a fixed height set on the container? Can we see some code?

Comment: What css rules (explicit/inherited) are applied to the div?

Answer (score 2):

if the div is of fixed height, you can simply remove the css attribute of height, and it should take care of it.

otherwise, you can go the good 'ol fashioned:

```
$("#div").css("height", number + 'px');
```

Answer (score 2):

either you set the height you want using:

```
$('your div selector').height(the value you want);
```

or don't give it a height at all and all of it parents and then it will expand automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ID").css({"height":"auto"});
```

Type that in after your $.ajax() request.  You can also replace "auto" with a more specific value if you fancy.  The key really is just calling a CSS change after the ajax request, so the height will be modified after.